# Авторизация пользователя в modx REVO

Tags: php, modx, revo

Здравствуйте.
С modx revo знаком слабо, но есть задача:
сделать закрытую страничку, доступ к которой будет только для авторизованных пользователей. Регистрировать пользователей будет админ.
Что я сделал:

---

- -Создал «группу ресурсов», контексты: web, mgr.
- -Создал политику доступа (Custom-view), разрешения: list, view.
- -Создал группу пользователя. Доступ к контекстам: web, mgr, политика доступа: Custom-view. Доступ к группам ресурсов: web, mgr, политика
  доступа: Custom-view.
- -Создал пользователя «UserTest». Галку поставил — «Активный». Права доступа: добавил пользователя в созданную ранее группу.
- -Создал страницу, назначил один из шаблонов. Галка «Опубликован». Назначил группу ресурсов, которую создал ранее.

---

- Неавторизованный пользователь не видит контента страницы.
  Администратор — видит. UserTest: пытаюсь залогиниться через странцу
  /manager, но страница просто перезагружается, ни на что не ругается.
  В админке, в редактировании пользователя, увеличивается счётчик
  «Количество входов». Контент закрытой страницы не доступен.
- — Я добавлял контекст mgr — думал, что поможет, но по факту мне нужен
  только web. В интернете написано, что есть стандартный сниппет
  «login», который позволяет сделать авторизацию, но на этом сайте нет
  этого сниппета. В modx evo можно установить модуль через вкладку
  «Модули» — «Extras», в revo такого не нашёл. В интернете написано,
  что надо пользоваться Package Manager'ом или типа того, но его я тоже
  не нашел.

— **Вопрос: Как залогиниться пользователем?**

P.S. Где посмотреть версию сайта? Слева сверху надпись: MODX Revolution 2.2.13-pl (traditional) — оно?

Comment: По поводу версии - да, это оно. По поводу авторизации - давно не копал MODx, но логиниться юзер должен точно не через админку (manager), почитайте профильные статьи в сети, либо дождитесь ответа здесь.

Comment: @DaemonHK , спасибо. Вот и получается: как тогда ставить Package Manager, чтобы поставить сниппет Login, чтобы сделать авторизацию)

Comment: А для чего нужен этот сниппет? Для авторизации через админку? Нафиг. Ищите сниппеты/модули для нормальной авторизации

Comment: @DaemonHK Всё, разобрался. Я не мог найти установщик модулей. Нашёл "Система" - "Управление пакетами"